# pattern matching for 2 forward slash using regex in java

Tags: regex

I would like to do pattern matching for following text in my word file, I am not sure how I can use pattern matcher

```
(P // TRIF)
(P)
(U//TRIF)
(U)
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex;
public class ExtractDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "I have a ( U) but I (P) like my (P//TRIF) better (U//TRIF).";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(P|U|P//TRIF|U//TRIF)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
            animals.add(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to match.  Can you show us some actual data?

Comment: What is the actual [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?. Try to add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches `U`, `P`, `P`, `U`

If you would like to match `(P // TRIF)` or  `(P)` or  `(U//TRIF)` or  `(U)` you could change the order in your alteration to
[`(P//TRIF|U//TRIF|P|U)`](https://regex101.com/r/afYmkL/1)

[Demo output Java](http://rextester.com/GSZL27742)

If you want to capture the text including the surrounding parenthesis in a group, you could try:

[`(\(\s*(?:P|U|P//TRIF|U//TRIF)\))`](https://regex101.com/r/jgJJTI/1)

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String input = "I have a ( U) but I (P) like my (P//TRIF) better (U//TRIF).";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\(\\s*(?:P|U|P//TRIF|U//TRIF)\\))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
        animals.add(m.group());
    }
}
```

[Demo output Java](http://rextester.com/GTE82238)

Another way to match this could be

[`\(\s*[PU](?://TRIF)?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/xz3Ixs/1)

[Demo output Java](http://rextester.com/GXEMJ96113)